# Master Theorem confusion with the three cases

Tags: algorithm, divide-and-conquer, recurrence

I know that we can apply the Master Theorem to find the running time of a divide and conquer algorithm, when the recurrence relation has the form of:

```
T(n) = a*T(n/b) + f(n)
```

We know the following :

- `a` is the number of subproblems that the algorithm divides the original problem
- `b` is the size of the sun-problem i.e `n/b`
- and finally.. `f(n)` encompasses the cost of dividing the problem and combining the results of the subproblems.

Now we then find something (I will come back to the term "something")
and we have 3 cases to check.

1. The case that `f(n) = O(n^log(b)a-ε)` for some ε>0; Then `T(n)` is `O(n*log(b)a)`
2. The case that `f(n) = O(n^log(b)a)` ; Then `T(n)` is `O(n^log(b)a * log n)`.
3. If `n^log(b)a+ε = O(f(n))` for some constant `ε > 0`, and if `a*f(n/b) =< cf(n)` for some constant
   `c < 1` and almost all n, then `T(n) = O(f(n))`.

All fine, I am recalling the term something. How we can use general examples (i.e uses variables and not actual numbers) to decide which case the algorithm is in?

In instance. Consider the following:

```
T(n) = 8T(n/2) + n
```

So `a = 8`, `b = 2` and `f(n) = n`

How I will proceed then? How can I decide which case is? While the function f(n) = some big-Oh notation how these two things are comparable?
The above is just an example to show you where I don't get it, so the question is in general.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As CLRS suggests, the basic idea is comparing `f(n)` with `n^log(b)a` i.e. n to the power (log a to the base b). In your hypothetical example, we have:

1. `f(n) = n`
2. `n^log(b)a = n^3`, i.e. n-cubed as your recurrence yields 8 problems of half the size at every step.

Thus, in this case, `n^log(b)a` is **larger** because `n^3` is always *O(n)* and the solution is: `T(n) = θ(n^3)`.

Clearly, the number of subproblems vastly outpaces the work (linear, `f(n) = n`) you are doing for each subproblem. Thus, the intuition tells and master theorem verifies that it is the `n^log(b)a` that dominates the recurrence.

There is a subtle technicality where the master theorem says that `f(n)` should be not only smaller than `n^log(b)a` O-wise, it should be smaller *polynomially*.

Comment: Hey, thanks. You mean that *always* we compare the same thing n^log(b)a with f(n) or is that just in this example?

Comment: @John, yes, always, that is what Master Theorem says. Once you get the recurrence right, you can almost blindly apply the master method and that of course needs practice. I also suggest you take a look at Mathematics for Computer Science (a free book!) -- google it and see the chapter on recurrences in there.